# Autoscale Vlan Selection in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing Vlan selection with region ID. In editing Autoscale policy vlan, there is ANY in the select box in some cases. Which case can user select ANY in the select box? ANY is not shown in a certain private Vlan.

[image: Any is not shown]

[image: Any is shown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified that "**Any**" is displayed when you clean the box, did you try this? This is possible in Private and Public boxes.